angular unit test coverage report html is empty
Somehow I have an empty index.html in coverage report folder after running "ng test --code-coverage":

I tried once and saw the report html file is filled with each component coverage but cannot make it out any more.
and here is the karma.conf.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        webpack: { node: { fs: 'empty' } },
        basePath: './',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-safari-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
            jasmine: {
                random: false,
                verboseDeprecations: true
            }
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/SecurusOnline'),
            subdir: '.',
            reporters: [
                { type: 'html' },
                { type: 'text-summary' },
            ],
            check: { // Optional: Enforce code coverage thresholds
                global: {
                statements: 80,
                branches: 80,
                functions: 80,
                lines: 80,
                },
            },
            'report-config': {
                html: {subdir: 'html'}
            },
            verbose: true // output config used by istanbul for debugging
        },
        files: ['src/test.ts'],
        include: ['src/**/*.spec.ts', 'src/**/*.d.ts', 'src/polyfills.ts'],
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        flags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-web-security', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 30000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 30000,
        captureTimeout: 40000
    })
}

If reversed to use karma-istanbul-coverage-reporter, the result is the same:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        webpack: { node: { fs: 'empty' } },
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-safari-launcher'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],

        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
            dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
            combineBrowserReports: true,
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
            skipFilesWithNoCoverage: true,
            'report-config': {
                html: {subdir: 'html'}
            },
            thresholds: {
                emitWarning: false, 
                global: {
                    statements: 100,
                    lines: 100,
                    branches: 100,
                    functions: 100
                },
                each: {
                    statements: 100,
                    lines: 100,
                    branches: 100,
                    functions: 100,
                    overrides: {
                        'baz/component/**/*.js': {
                            statements: 98
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        client: {
            clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
            jasmine: {
                random: false,
                verboseDeprecations: true
            }
        },
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
        },
        files: ['src/test.ts'],
        include: ['src/**/*.spec.ts', 'src/**/*.d.ts', 'src/polyfills.ts'],
        reporters: ['coverage-istanbul'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        flags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-web-security', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        singleRun: true,
        watch: true
    })
}

Any idea what could be the possible reason? Thanks!

What about reverting back to karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter?

@KavindaSenarathne Updated and added config for karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter, and the result is the same, empty html

What happens if you remove this custom Karma config and run the same command? By default, an HTML report should be generated if --code-coverage argument is there

@davidlj95 If karma.conf.js is removed still get an empty report generated in another folder under dist.
